# Getting PHP error when trying to bind to onEditionChange event

Tags: events

I'm trying to bind to the onEditionChange event with something like this:

```
craft()->on('onEditionChange', function (Event $event) {
    craft()->womb->sendEvent($event);
});
```

However, i'm getting this error:

```
Undefined offset: 1
```

Seems it expects an dot in there. Is there another way to bind to this event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that particular event is raised from [AppBehavior](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior) (and therefore [WebApp](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/web/WebApp)), it doesn't follow the same `component.eventName` [syntax](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference) that the other Craft events use and you can't use [craft->on()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/web/WebApp#on-detail) to register to listen to it.

You can register to listen to it through the traditional [Yii method](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/327/events-explained), though.  This should work for you:

```
craft()->onEditionChange = function (Event $event) {
    craft()->womb->sendEvent($event);
};
```